# Block URL with path in /etc/hosts?

Tags: hosts

I am working on OSX and I want to block access to an individual URL (a twitter profile) in `/etc/hosts`.

Is this possible? I've tried adding:

```
127.0.0.1      twitter.com/mypath
127.0.0.1      www.twitter.com/mypath
```

and then running `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache`, but it doesn't seem to do anything, I can still see the page.

Comment: You can't put URLs in there. Just hostnames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `/etc/hosts` is static DNS lookup table.
It comes to play way before you use url.

When you try to open URL this happens

1. DNS resolution (here is `/etc/hosts` active) > resolve twitter.com to ip address
2. tcp connection establiched to ip
3. then http protocol come to play